# IndexError when trying to use second table on a page using pandas read_html

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe from the second table on a webpage, and getting this error when running my code:

"Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                        File "hup.py", line 51, in                                                                                                                                        full_table2 = dataframe2[1]                                                                                                                                         IndexError: list index out of range"

I am able to print the dataframe at the index specified, so I know the data is present. I have similar code, using the table at index 0, which runs smoothly. Code is as follows, the 'full_football_ref' variable specifies the link I'm using:

```
        dataframe2 = pd.read_html(full_football_ref)
        full_table2 = dataframe2[1]
```

Comment: Please include more code and full error traceback.

Comment: Could you also include the URL you are attempting to scrape? The error suggests you are only getting one of the tables you wanted.